# Function not receiving receiving userinput from <form> tag

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying to make a simple program involving a musical interval game. It will have the user trying to answer the correct interval with a given set of notes. However, I'm having a problems with my `check()` function, which will read the user's answer and check it with the correct answer. The problem is that when I run the program and try to click the `check` button, I won't get any response.

Here's the JavaScript code:

```
var notes = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G'];
var accidentals = ['b','#'];
var notesFull = [];

for (var i = 0; i < notes.length; i++) {
    notesFull.push(notes[i] + accidentals[0]);
    notesFull.push(notes[i]);
    notesFull.push(notes[i] + accidentals[1]);
}
notesFull.splice(5,2);
notesFull.splice(12,2);

var intervals = ["U", "m2", "M2", "m3", "M3", "P4", "T", "P5", "m6", "M6", "m7", "M7"];
function game() {
    var setIntOne = Math.floor(Math.random()*notesFull.length);
    var setIntTwo = Math.floor(Math.random()*notesFull.length);
    var oneToTwo = setIntOne - setIntTwo;
    if (oneToTwo < 0) {
        oneToTwo = oneToTwo * -1
    }
    var ques = "What is the interval going UP from " + notesFull[setIntTwo] + " to " + notesFull[setIntOne] + "?";
    document.getElementById("ques").innerHTML = ques;
}

function check() {
    var usrInp = document.getElementById("usrInp");
    if (usrInp.elements[0].value === intervals[oneToTwo]) {
        var resp = "Correct!";
    }
    else if (usrInp.elements[0].value === "null") {
        var resp = "Please input an interval";
    }
    else {
        var resp = "Sorry! Try again";
    }
    document.getElementById("resp").innerHTML = resp;
}
```

And here's the HTML code:

```
<button onclick="game()">Click here for test</button>
<p id="ques"></p>
<form id="usrInp">
    Type Answer Here: <input type="text" name="usrAns">
</form>
<button onclick="check()">Check</button>
<p id="resp"></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the console in the browser:

> "oneToTwo is not defined"

Maybe you can move your `var oneToTwo` outside of the function.

For example:

```
var notes = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G'];
var accidentals = ['b','#'];
var notesFull = [];
var oneToTwo;
for (var i = 0; i < notes.length; i++) {
    notesFull.push(notes[i] + accidentals[0]);
    notesFull.push(notes[i]);
    notesFull.push(notes[i] + accidentals[1]);
}
notesFull.splice(5,2);
notesFull.splice(12,2);

var intervals = ["U", "m2", "M2", "m3", "M3", "P4", "T", "P5", "m6", "M6", "m7", "M7"];
function game() {
    var setIntOne = Math.floor(Math.random()*notesFull.length);
    var setIntTwo = Math.floor(Math.random()*notesFull.length);
    oneToTwo = setIntOne - setIntTwo;
    if (oneToTwo < 0) {
        oneToTwo = oneToTwo * -1
    }
    var ques = "What is the interval going UP from " + notesFull[setIntTwo] + " to " + notesFull[setIntOne] + "?";
    document.getElementById("ques").innerHTML = ques;
}

function check() {
    var usrInp = document.getElementById("usrInp");
    if (usrInp.elements[0].value === intervals[oneToTwo]) {
        var resp = "Correct!";
    }
    else if (usrInp.elements[0].value === "null") {
        var resp = "Please input an interval";
    }
    else {
        var resp = "Sorry! Try again";
    }
    document.getElementById("resp").innerHTML = resp;
}
```

Comment: I'm using a school-issued chromebook, and they've blocked the use of the console :/

Comment: @AZNPNOY2000
I have moved the `var oneToTwo;` outside of the function and updated my answer.

Comment: Nevermind. It worked. Thanks btw. Now just need to work on getting the right calculation...